# Minimal container ubuntu image docker like

Tags: process, upstart, heroku, lxc

I'm playing around with LXC. My goal is to run a single process within a container and I'm now focusing on processes running within my container.

When I create a basic LXC template on ubuntu 12.04, I've got about ten processes running (including cron, ttys, init ...). When I do the same with docker or Heroku dynos (using `ps -ef`), I've got only the process I launched. This lead to 2 questions:

- Docker doesn't use the `lxc-create` command. `rootfs` of the containers (I suppose) are custom images downloaded. How do they tweak this image to make it run only one process ?
- Dynos on Heroku have only one process running (the one users intend to run) but support the automatic restart of the process if this one crashes. I know this is possible if the process is supervised by `init` or `upstart`, but that means that at least `init` should run within the dyno (and that's no the case). How do they achieve this ?

These questions are quite complex, I'm not looking for a detailed answer here but just general ideas on how this work.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some basic instructions on creating a base image in the [docker docs](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/baseimages/) and have a look at the `mkimage`-scripts in the [source code's contrib directory](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/tree/master/contrib). What it boils down to is you use the `debootstrap` tool to create a ubuntu/debian root filesystem, tar this and import it into docker. An example for building a minimal ubuntu precise (12.04 LTS) image from scratch would be:

```
    debootstrap --verbose --variant=minbase --include='iproute,iputils-ping' --arch=amd64 precise /tmp/precise/ `curl -s http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt | head -1`
```

The last curl bit will pick a ubuntu mirror close to your machine's location, you can also simply pass a standard ubuntu mirror url - note that this mirror picked will now be hard-coded into your new images `etc/apt/sources.list`, so you might want to amend it before packaging by editing it according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

The supervision of running processes within docker containers is something that is not the task of your containers themselves - they are just in charge of running any given command in an isolated environment. The daemon-management part should happen on your docker host machine, i.e. you could write an upstart job for each of your desired containers.

Comment: *Late reply* Thank you, I found the answer to my question a longtime ago: they have their own `/sbin/init` binary, containers doesn't go through the all init process, that is why `ps -ef` only shows one ps.